# Magento 2.2.4 generation does not exists

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I have installed Magento 2.2.4 with composer. Everything is working but when I am running this command.

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

It is giving me an error

```
**[RuntimeException] Source class "\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Virtual" forMagento\Payment\Model\Method\VirtualLogger" generation does not exist.**
```

I have cleared all cache and removed these folders also

```
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
```

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurs only when you have a plugin for  class "Psr\Log\LoggerInterface"

In our case, it was in WeltPixel's extension

app/code/WeltPixel/Backend/etc/di.xml

Removing the content

```
 <type name="Psr\Log\LoggerInterface">
         <plugin name="weltpixel-backend-logger"
                 type="WeltPixel\Backend\Plugin\Logger" sortOrder="15"/>
 </type>
```

solved the problem.

Just search your file system for text

name="Psr\Log\LoggerInterface"

and remove the plugin temporarily until the time we have an official solution on GitHub issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14950

Comment: Thank you for your response, Actually we rolled back to Magento 2.2.2 because of this issue. So I hope they will fix this issue in their next version.

Comment: Okay. However, are you using any of WeltPixel's extension?

Comment: Yes, I am using weltpixel backend, quickview and google tag manager.

Comment: Thanks, this happened when I added \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface to an Observer then tried to setup:upgrade on a production site (worked fine in development....)

rm -rf generated/code generated/metadata
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_NZ

Resolved this for me. (Note remove en_NZ if not NZ language for theme/css etc)

Happened in Magento 2.3.0 so still appears to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

1、note: var/generation has been moved to generated/code and var/di has been moved to generated/metadata in m2.2, so we only delete generation.

`rm -rf generation/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/composer_home/cache/*`

2、try :

```
composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

ditto. i also see a similar issue logged on https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14950

note: var/generation has been moved to generated/code and var/di has been moved to generated/metadata in m2.2

edit: i've also contacted WeltPixel following some comments on github and they have said.

> "We are aware of this issue that came with Magento 2.2.4 , and we already fixed it. The fix will be included in the next products releases next week, after all tests are completed."

Comment: So I need to remove generated/code and generated/metadata content and try again?

Comment: var/gen etc was just a fyi given the code you added.
i don't know the solution as yet but will also watch that github thread with interest.

Comment: Hopefully it will be fixed in next version.

Answer (score 0):

First clear all the cache by running following command in terminal:

```
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/composer_home/cache/*
```

Then try the following:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Hopefully it will solve your issue.